# measuring runtime of bash script with & parameter in the body

Tags: linux, performance, bash

How can I measure the runtime of my script which is like this :

```
#! /bin/bash
start1=`date +%s`
./a &
./a &
./a &
./a &
./a &

end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start1))
echo "$runtime"
```

the measured time is 0 because all the command run in background and at the same time 
what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`wait`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wait+1) command to wait for the processes to finish, before measuring the time

```
#! /bin/bash
start1=`date +%s`
./a &
./a &
./a &
./a &
./a &

wait #  <----------------

end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start1))
echo "$runtime"
```

You can also use the [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command for better and more accurate results:

```
time {
    ./a &
    ./a &
    ./a &
    ./a &
    ./a &

    wait #  <----------------
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `time` command, which I didn't know about, but be aware that your link is wrong: the `time` you're calling here is [a bash built-in keyword](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html), not the [`/usr/bin/time` executable](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) you linked to. `/usr/bin/time` doesn't support pipes or braces.

Comment: @JeffBowman Thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware of the difference